# How to hide hosts in grafana dashboard?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

***This is the following scenario:***

I have installed node-exporter (Prometheus exporter) in few EC2 instances for collecting technical information such as CPU, Disk, Memory statistics, etc. I've added Prometheus as a data source for the Grafana server.

I'm able to get metrics of all the instances that I have configured which is awesome.

Now I want only a few machines' data, rather than all the instances which I've configured.

1. How can I get a few machines' data metrics without removing node exporters in those machines?
2. Is there any option in Grafana for hiding the hosts which I don't want to monitor?

Comment: pls post your metric and the raw result of it. That is done just by adding a label with the clause that you want to show or not show

Comment: the raw metric, not the screenshot. Just like you would use in prometheus and few examples of the result as text as well, not pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grafana's [templating and variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/) to create dashboards that focus on a subset of machines and are flexible in selecting which instance metrics to render.